# sqlite delete row by onItemLongClick gridview sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, gridview, nullpointerexception

i have a gridview that get data from an sqlite database and i want to delete a row by onItemLongClick but i get a error i cannot solve it

```
@Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                               int position, long id)
{
    dataBase.delete(mDBHelper.TABLE_LIENS, mDBHelper.toString()
                                           + "="
                                           + mLienList.get(position), null);

    mLienList.remove(position);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    Toast.makeText(Main2ActivityAdmin.this, "Lien supprimer", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    return true;
}
```

stack trace is:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: PID: 21230 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.delete(java.lang.Stri‌​ng, java.lang.String, java.lang.String[])' on a null object reference
```

Comment: did you see the last param of `onItemLongClick`? this is the row ID that you can use to delete the particular row in your db

Comment: i dont get it !

Comment: add your log stack trace!

Answer (score 1):

According to your stack trace you don't initial your SQLiteDatabase, so when use it, exception has been occurred. see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31072142/6340959). it gives you an idea to modify your code.

Answer (score 0):

if error coming from sqlite, you have to make sure that your **whereClause** is correct value

```
db.delete(table, whereClause, whereArgs);
```

and make sure you have initialize your database variable, in my case

```
db = new DB(this);
db.open();
```

Comment: i already initialize my database